# Magento 2 SQLSTATE[42S22]: while create product?

Tags: magento2, database

I'm using magento v2.1.7 with two website, two store. While creating product get error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'e_attr.store_id' in 'field list', query was: SELECT
>   `e_attr`.`store_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity` AS `e_attr` ON e.entity_id = e_attr.entity_id
>   WHERE (e_attr.attribute_id = '') AND (e.entity_id = '127').

I'm try redindex, plush cache. but it not success

Add more info
I checked in exception.log get message

> main.CRITICAL: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
>   Unknown column 'e_attr.store_id' in 'field list' in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228